# How to return 2 arrays after saving data to mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need help with code below. I get an array of items from the client then the goal is to save them in mongodb and return the list classified as 'saved' and 'failed' items. sample of failed items are those that are duplicate on a unique attribute.

I know the code below will not work because of variable scope. how do i get around it? the code below returns an empty array for both savedItems and failedItems. Thanks!

```
router.post('/addItems', async (req, res, next) => {
  let items = req.body;
  let result = {
    savedItems: [],
    failedItems: []
  };

  function saveData() {
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      item = items[i];

      Model.create({ ...item }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          result.failedItems.push(item);
        } else {
          result.savedItems.push(item);
        }
      });
    }
    return result;
  }

  saveData().then(result => {
    res.send({
      results: result
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.post('/addItems', async (req, res, next) => {
// use try catch when use async
try {
    let items = req.body;
    let result = {
        savedItems: [],
        failedItems: []
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        const item = items[i];
        // use the returned promise instead of callback for Model.create 
        const data = await Model.create({ ...item });
        result.savedItems.push(item);

        // if also need to handle failed item in result use anathor try catch inside
        /*try {
            const data = await Model.create({ ...item });
            result.savedItems.push(item);
        } catch( err ) {
            result.failedItems.push(item);
        }*/
    }
    res.send({
        results: result
    });
} catch( err ) {
    // To all the errors unexpected errors + thrown rejected promises
    res.send({
        error: err
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your saveData method didn't return a promise, try this

```
function saveData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let items = req.body;
    let result = {
      savedItems: [],
      failedItems: []
    };
    let promises = [];
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      item = items[i];
      let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        Model.create({ ...item }, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            result.failedItems.push(item);
          } else {
            result.savedItems.push(item);
          }
          resolve();
        });
      });
      promises.push(promise);
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => resolve(result));
  })
}
```

Comment: @GMKaiRoger  that's because Model.create is async, check my updated answer.